# Neotree window not resizable

Tags: window, neotree

I get this message when I try to resize the [neotree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree) window using my mouse:

> No resizable window on the left of this one

Does anyone know how I can make the neotree window re-sizable?

Answer (score 14):

Found a solution.

It works if I put this into my config:

```
  (setq neo-window-fixed-size nil)
```

The only downside is that neotree does not remember the window width. When you switch buffers it will reset the width back to the default value. There is a related [issue](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/issues/129) on github.

Comment: However you can set a width with `(setq neo-window-width 20)` to which neotree will reopen -- so there should be a way to change the value according to the previously used width, if you have the time, inclination and emacs-lisp chops.

Answer (score 2):

Put this on your emacs configuration file:

```
;; Set the neo-window-width to the current width of the
;; neotree window, to trick neotree into resetting the
;; width back to the actual window width.
;; Fixes: https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/issues/262
(eval-after-load "neotree"
  '(add-to-list 'window-size-change-functions
                (lambda (frame)
                  (let ((neo-window (neo-global--get-window)))
                    (unless (null neo-window)
                      (setq neo-window-width (window-width neo-window)))))))
```

(from: https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/issues/262)